# FB iOS SDK How to test: Send request and receive it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sdk, facebook-app-requests

im a iOS game developer, im new in this stuff of how integrate facebook SDK. I need facebook to sent and receive virtual gifts from device to device, such as coins, lives, so on.
I already logged in and i use the code of making a request in the facebook developers page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/

My NSlog says the request was sent.

i saw that i need this code in my AppDelegate.cpp to receive the URL that contains the request

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    self.openedURL = url;
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

I put the receive code already. But when i run `FB_ProcessIncomingURL();` form the page above, the line:

```
NSString *urlString = [appDelegate.openedURL fragment];
```

returns me null

Did i do something wrong? Or when i have to run this `FB_ProcessIncomingURL()`?

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "when i run FB_ProcessIncomingURL()"? How do you run it?

Comment: I try it in another Mac and worked!, seems like a bug, or something wrong with my Mac.